# Where is the hashKey variable defined in the source for the ngRepeat directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hoping to understand more about how more complex directives work, I was looking at [the source of ngRepeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js). On [line 205](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L205), a `hashFnLocals`variable is defined to be an object with an `$id` property. But this property is assigned a value of `hashKey`, which I don't see defined anywhere. Is it defined in another script, which it gets access to when they're concatenated during the build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a function declared in angular.js:

```
function hashKey(obj) {
    var objType = typeof obj,
        key;

    if (objType == 'object' && obj !== null) {
        if (typeof (key = obj.$$hashKey) == 'function') {
            // must invoke on object to keep the right this
            key = obj.$$hashKey();
        } else if (key === undefined) {
            key = obj.$$hashKey = nextUid();
        }
    } else {
        key = obj;
    }

    return objType + ':' + key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's defined [in apis.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/61f2767ce65562257599649d9eaf9da08f321655/src/apis.js#L16), starts on line 16.